# How do I identify a good quality replacement battery for an iPhone?

Tags: battery, iphone

My iPhone 4s battery was dying, so I replaced it (the battery). But the replacement battery (which was a cheap one from eBay) is pretty poor.

The replacement battery looked exactly like the original one (to my untrained eye at least).

Is there a way in which I can distinguish a good-quality replacement battery from a poor-quality one?

Comment: Most batteries sold on eBay (and the like) are actually used originals, scavenged from broken phones or maybe extracted from the recycling chain. No wonder they don't hold up – they might be older than the one you intended to replace.

Comment: @sekdiy yeah, I'm not too surprised. Is there a way I can tell a new one from a used one? Are they available factory-sealed or something like that?

Comment: @AE No, you can't find them factory-sealed. I don't really know how you would tell if it's good quality short of knowing if it's an original pulled from another iPhone. I can tell you two things I've learned about replacement batteries: 1. I don't care if it's not politically correct, don't ever, EVER buy replacement batteries from China. Bad batteries catching fire could injure you, ruin your iPhone, or even burn your house down. 2. I've found replacement iPhone batteries from ifixit.com to work pretty well (I'm not affiliated with iFixit). So, you might check them out.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @RedEagle2000, unfortunately they're in the states and I'm in the uk - so shipping would cost nearly as much as the battery and take a while. I'll try to find a UK equivalent.

Comment: @AE You're welcome and good luck with the search.